# 'QObject' is an ambiguous base of 'Recorder'

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qtcore, qobject

I'm trying to use QTimer, which inherits QObject, in my newly created class. However I try it I keep getting the error  *'QObject' is an ambiguous base of 'Recorder'* . I did try my best to avoid ambiguity in my simple program but still got stuck with it.
Here's the structure of my classes.

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Dialog w;    
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

dialog.h: mainwindow UI

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include "detector.h"
#include <QDialog>
#include <QtCore>

namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
    Detector myDetector;
```

detector.h: detector window UI

```
#ifndef DETECTOR_H
#define DETECTOR_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QObject>
#include "actualrec.h"

namespace Ui {
class Detector;
}

class Detector : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Detector(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Detector();
    void run();

private:
    ActualRec theDetector;
    Ui::Detector *ui;
```

actualrec.h: detector code

```
#ifndef ACTUALREC_H
#define ACTUALREC_H

#include <QtCore>
#include <QObject>    
#include <QImage>
#include "recorder.h"

class ActualRec : public QThread
{
public:
    ActualRec();
    void run();

private:        
    Recorder theRecorder;
```

recorder.h: recorder code, where I want to use my QTimer

```
#ifndef RECORDER_H
#define RECORDER_H

#include <QtCore>

class Recorder : public QThread, public QObject
{

public:
    Recorder();
    void run();

private:
    QTimer* theTimer;
```

recorder.cpp constructor has

```
 *theTimer = new QTimer(this);
```

the output is following:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTNCV.png

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: `QThread` is already `QObject`, no need to inherit it twice.

Comment: @vahancho i did actually think about that but when i don't include public QObject I get the error **no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'QTimer' and 'QTimer*')
       *theTimer = new QTimer(this);
                 ^**

Comment: I would eventually also leave out the * in the constructor since theTimer is already a pointer. While this will not solve the problem, its still wrong. By the way please provide the error in textform also, do not add an image as information. the image link will get invalid pretty soon, so please update your question.

Comment: @isADon, because you should write `theTimer = new QTimer(this);` instead. Remove the *.

Comment: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Threads_Events_QObjects

Comment: What do you need the timer for?  If you want to periodically record stuff in the thread and wake it up, you could just use a timed wait on a QWaitCondition.  Additionally when stopping the thread, you can notify that wait condition to get it to wake up early.
Since the wait time will not ever be all that accurate (and neither is QTimer), to dither the wait time, use a QElapsedTimer to measure the progress of time and adjust your wait timer appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have *several* issues in your code:

1) **Wrong usage of thread with Qt**

```
class Recorder : public QThread, public QObject
```

a) It is enough to inherit QThread without explicitly inheriting QObject since QThread inherits QObject.

b) Even if you did this, historically, `QObject` ought to be the first base in the list in a general case.

c) However, you may wish to reconsider how to use your threads. This is one way, but necessarily the best.

2) **Allocating an object for `QTimer` on the heap**

Why are you allocating memory on the heap for a timer in the first place? It is OK to allocate it on the stack, especially since it is a member. That way, you would not need to deal with the `this` hassle either. The whole memory management becomes a lot simpler.

3) **Not utilizing Q_NULLPTR**

You ought to use it instead of 0 for the default values of the parents.

4) **Including the whole QtCore module**

```
#include <QtCore>
```

You should only include the parts that you eventually use. This is a brute-force way of including things.

Therefore, write something like this instead:

```
class Recorder : public QThread
{

public:
    Recorder();
    void run();

private:
    QTimer theTimer;
```

Of course, if you use the threading mechanism the other way around in Qt, then it is perfectly fine to write this instead for the inheritance:

```
class Recorder : public QObject
```

but then your code would need some other change, so the code is broken as it is now, either way.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. how should I initialize my QTimer in the constructor?

Comment: @isADon: there is no need to initialize it given the constructor arguments you have used before. It is done automatically for you. Just start using it. You need to use it as `theTimer.` instead of `theTimer->` for sure.

Comment: I would +1, if you didn't suggest to inherit from QThread. Read [this](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Threads_Events_QObjects)

Comment: @BЈовић: your knowledge is outdated (~1.5 years old). Update it: http://woboq.com/blog/qthread-you-were-not-doing-so-wrong.html It is fine either way in different scenarios said by one of the recent core Qt developers, not someone who wrote something many years ago and does not even work on Qt anymore. ;)

Comment: @FinalContest thanks this solution did let me compile it without any errors. however when i connect theTimer to my private slot setFalse() like this: **connect(&theTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(setFalse()));** I get an error **QObject::connect: No such slot QThread::setFalse()** which makes sense since my setFalse is in Recorder::setFalse() and not in QThread? why does it call it from qThread?

Comment: was able to fix it myself. a header was missing in the .pro file for some reason

Answer (score 3):

QThread already inherits QObject, and you can't inherit from two classes both inheriting QObject themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You shall no inherit QObject twice. This is because signals and slots are mapped by integers and the ids can collide with each.

This also applies to any object that inherits from QObject.

```
class BadClass : public QTimer, public Dialog
{
};
```